# What is a "necessary condition" to observe stationary probabilities?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes

In our Stat. Mech class the professor said that the detailed balance condition,
\begin{align}
K_{ij}P_{j}=K_{ji}P_{i}
\end{align}
is a sufficient but not necessary condition to observe stationary probabilities.
My question is then, what is a necessary condition to observe stationary probabilities? And how to quantify this necessity condition?
Where Kij is the transition probability from j to i and Pi,j are the stationary probabilities.

Comment: It’s usually a good idea to give even the smallest bit of context to your equations and problem…

Answer (score 1):

To have a steady state condition, you must have the *net* rate of transition into any one state (from all other states) be equal to the *net* rate of transition out of that state (into all other states.)  Mathematically, this would read as
$$
\sum_j K_{ij} P_j = \sum_j K_{ji} P_i
$$
for all indices $i$.

It should be obvious that if the detailed-balance condition holds (in your original question) then this condition holds as well; the detailed-balance condition says that each individual term on the left is matched by an individual term on the right.   But you can also concoct situations where the probabilities are stationary but detailed balance is not observed;  for example:
$$
P_1 = P_2 = P_3 = \frac13 \qquad K_{12} = K_{23} = K_{31} = 1 \qquad K_{21} = K_{32} = K_{13} = 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Stationary probabilities $P_i$ arise in any case when $K_{ij}$ are correct conditional probabilities, that is, they have the following properties
$$
\forall i,j\quad K_{ij} \geq 0,\quad \sum_{i} K_{ij} = 1
$$
The existence of stationary probabilities means that the system of equations
$$
\sum_j K_{ij} P_j = P_i
$$
has a solution $P$ such that $P_i \geq 0$, $\sum_i P_i = 1$. In the case when the probability matrix $K$ is irreducible, the corresponding system is ergodic and the stationary state is unique. The matrix $K$ is irreducible if for any pair of states $i,j$ either $K_{ij} \neq 0$, or there is a finite chain of intermediate states $l_1,\ldots l_n$ such that
$$
K_{il_1}\left(\prod_{a=1}^{n-1}K_{l_al_{a+1}}\right) K_{l_nj}\neq 0.
$$